# I don't know about key in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm learning flutter
I don't really understand the difference between these codes

Codes

```
const MyApp({super.key});
const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key : key);
```

What's the difference? Also,what circumstances does the use change?

I searched the official document and learned about Stateless Widget and Stateful Widget, but I don't understand it

Comment: it's the same, just [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)

Answer (score 1):

It is really syntetic sugar. In this case it mean that instead of

```
const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key : key);
```

you can write:

```
const MyApp({super.key});
```

you pass a key to the MyApp widget and it pass it in to the super constructor. So this is not about keys only:

```
class A {
  const A({this.index = 0});
  final int index;
}

class B extends A {
  const B({super.index});
}
```